# Libphonenumber - Validate number with country code

Tags: c#, libphonenumber

I am using the C# port for [googlelibphonenumber](https://github.com/erezak/libphonenumber-csharp) and I am trying to validate that a phone number is in the correct format. I have the country code and the number as two strings, how do I validate that, or parse, the number is in the correct format for the country code?

for example:
I have +44 & 02476 123987

or +1 & 345-432-432

I'm using an MVC5 application.

I have tried the following code, but it always seems to return invalid:

```
    var rawnumber = "02476 123987";
    var cc = "GB";

    var util = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
    var b = new PhoneNumber.Builder();

        b.CountryCode = util.GetCountryCodeForRegion(cc);
        b.RawInput = rawnumber;

    var number = b.Build();

    return util.IsValidNumber(number);
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `Parse` function to get the PhoneNumber object, e.g. `number = util.Parse(rawnumber, cc);` in the above case.  This is the standard method to use in this situation across `libphonenumber` ports.